# What exactly is meant by contact angle between two circles?

Tags: geometry

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects) wikipedia article, a contact angle $\phi$ is mentioned.

I am unsure if the angle is the [angle between the normal and the x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwpaq.png) or just the angle between the line formed by connecting the centers and the x axis.

Thanks!

Comment: Aren’t they the same for a pair of circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article section is about elastic collisions of disks in two dimensions and the contact angle is the angle between the velocity vector of one disk relative to the other and the line between the disks' centres at the moment of collision.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. However, how could you generalize this to Ovals for example? The line between the centers no longer corresponds to the normal line at the point of collision. Which one is used in this case?